# Which SE site should I use to ask about healthcare, fingerprints and smart cards?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working in the healthcare field. I have lots of questions, especially about [fingerprint](/questions/tagged/fingerprint)s and [smartcard](/questions/tagged/smartcard)s.

Where should I ask these questions?

Comment: There _was_ http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it . Not anymore.

Comment: What type of questions?

Comment: @ChrisF Such questions as 1) In what best case should healthcare use fingerprint?, 2) Can we use smart card as patient card, etc. ...